# Set-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation while using Addaudit Rule

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell, scripting

I am trying to run Powershell script to set Audit Rule on `C:\Windows\security` folder on my Windows 2008 box.

Below is the script:

```
$FileDirList = ("C:\Windows\security")
$AccountName     = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Everyone") 
$FileSystemRight = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$AuditFlag       = [System.Security.AccessControl.AuditFlags]::Failure
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None

#
#write-OSPBOSbuildLog  "Applying Audit Setting"
#     

foreach ($FileDirName in $FileDirList) {   
#write-OSPBOSbuildLog  ">>>>>  Appying audit setting to $FileDirName"

$AuditRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule       $AccountName, $FileSystemRight, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $AuditFlag 

$objACL = Get-ACL $FileDirname 

$objACL.AddAuditRule($AuditRule)

Set-ACL $FileDirname $objACL
```

But I am getting error as shown below:

```
Set-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. 
At C:\IBM\File-Perm.ps1:22 char:12 + Set-ACL <<<< $FileDirname $objACL + CategoryInfo :
PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows:String) [Set-Acl], 
UnauthorizedAccessException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
 System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Please help me understand what changes I need to do?